# TypeScript factory pattern and property doesnt exist?

Tags: typescript

I'm about to implement factory pattern on my nodejs app with typescript with following code for testing :

```
class userFactory {
  public constructor(type:string) { return new Admin() }
}

class Admin {
  public type:string;
  constructor(){
    this.type = "admin"
  }
  public pwd(){ return "200" }
}

let factory = new userFactory('admin');
console.log(factory.pwd())
```

When executing this, from console i receive following error : **index.ts:17:21 - error TS2339: Property 'pwd' does not exist on type 'userFactory'.**

Why i cannot access the Admin pwd method? could you explain me please ?

thank you

Comment: Eugene has given you a sensible alternative. But you wanted an explanation. Well it is as simple as so, the constructor of a class is supposed to have return type of that class. So what happens in your example is the new Admin() is cast to a userFactory, which is legal since userFactory has no properties on it that Admin doesn't have. A userFactory doesn't have a pwd method, ergo.

Comment: Hi, thanks for explanation, i am very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's better not to return a new object from the `userFactory` constructor. You can use a `create` method in your factory for code to work as expected.

```
class userFactory {
    create(type: string) {
        return new Admin();
    }
}

class Admin {
  public type:string;
  constructor(){
    this.type = "admin"
  }
  public pwd(){ return "200" }
}

let factory = new userFactory();
let admin = factory.create('admin');
console.log(admin.pwd());
```